# How do browsers handle rgb(percentage); for strange numbers

Tags: css, browser, colors, hex

This is related to CSS color codes:

For hexcode we can represent 16,777,216 colors from #000000 to #FFFFFF

According to W3C Specs, Valid RGB percentages fit in a range from (0.0% to 100.0%) essentially giving you 1,003,003,001 color combinations. (1001^3)

According to the specs:

> Values outside the device gamut should be clipped or mapped into the gamut when the gamut is 
>   known: the red, green, and blue values must be changed to fall within the range supported by 
>   the device. Users agents may perform higher quality mapping of colors from one gamut to 
>   another. For a typical CRT monitor, whose device gamut is the same as sRGB, the four rules 
>   below are equivalent:

I'm doubtful if browsers actually can render all these values. (but if they do please tell me and ignore the rest of this post)

Im assuming there's some mapping from rgb(percentage) to hex. (but again Im not really sure how this works)

Ideally I'd like to find out the function rgb(percentage)->HEX

If I had to guess it would probably be one of these 3.

1) Round to the nearest HEX

2) CEIL to the nearest HEX

3) FLOOR to the nearest HEX

Problem is I need to be accurate on the mapping and I have no idea where to search.
There's no way my eyes can differentiate color at that level, but maybe there's some clever way to test each of these 3.

It might also be browser dependent.  Can this be tested?

**EDIT:**

```
Firefox seems to round from empirical testing.
```

**EDIT:**

I'm looking through Firefox's source code right now,

```
nsColor.h
// A color is a 32 bit unsigned integer with four components: R, G, B
// and A.
typedef PRUint32 nscolor;
```

It seems Fiefox only has room for 255 values for each R,G and B.  Hinting that rounding might be the answer, but maybe somethings being done with the alpha channel.

Comment: If you can't tell the difference between `#000000` and `#000001`, why do you need the exact formula? Also a circuitous way of testing would be to display a block of the colour, hit Print Screen, and use the eyedropper tool of a graphics program to find out the resulting hex value.

Comment: I'm working on a type of parser I guess, obviously the end user shouldn't be able to tell the difference between #000000 and #000001, but the code needs to be equivalent on all accounts.  I do like the eyedropper idea as a first step though, thanks!

Comment: If the spec doesn't specify a mapping, then I expect it'll be browser dependent, or at least if it's not browser dependent, then it's just a coincidence that it's not. I imagine as long as you're consistent then you're being as accurate as you can be. Have you checked with firebug or some such on the computed style to see how it ends up?

Comment: This really, really, really sounds like something you shouldn't be doing outside of an academic/test environment. Different browsers treat fractions differently in CSS definitions (across the board; if you play with fractions of units for a while, you'll see what I mean). Just because it's a standard does not mean that you should use it in production. If these CSS definitions are generated by a program (server-side or js or whatever), a simple solution would be to do the math yourself so that it's consistent. If not... sigh... the interweb is cruel in this regard. Sorry if this is no help.

Comment: Thanks, your right this is purely for academic reasons.  I wanted to make a more uniform stylesheet, converting rgb percentage to an equivalent hex to increase compressibility.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution for Firefox anyways, thought you might like a follow up:

Looking through the source code I found a file:

nsCSSParser.cpp

For each rgb percentages it does the following:

1. It takes the percentage component multiplies it by 255.0f
2. Stores it in a float
3. Passes it into a function NSToIntRound
4. The result of NSToIntRound is stored into an 8 bit integer datatype,
       before it is combined with the other 2 components and an alpha
       channel

Looking for more detail on NSToIntRound:

```
nsCoord.h
inline PRInt32 NSToIntRound(float aValue)
{
  return NS_lroundf(aValue);
}
```

NSToIntRound is a wrapper function for NS_lroundf

```
nsMathUtils.h
inline NS_HIDDEN_(PRInt32) NS_lroundf(float x)
{
    return x >= 0.0f ? PRInt32(x + 0.5f) : PRInt32(x - 0.5f);
}
```

This function is actually very clever, took me a while to decipher (I don't really have a good C++ background).

Assuming x is positive

It adds 0.5f to x and then casts to an integer

If the fractional part of x was less than 0.5, adding 0.5 won't change the integer and the fractional part is truncated,

Otherwise the integer value is bumped by 1 and the fractional part is truncated.

1. So each component's percentage is first multiplied by 255.0f
2. Then Rounded and cast into a 32bit Integer
3. And then Cast again into an 8 bit Integer

I agree with most of you that say this appears to be a browser dependent issue, so I will do some further research on other browsers.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

> According to W3C Specs, Valid RGB percentages fit in a range from (0.0% to 100.0%) essentially giving you 1,003,003,001 color combinations. (1001^3)

No, more than that, because the precision is not limited to one decimal place. For example, this is valid syntax:

```
rgb(23.456% 78.90123456% 0%)
```

The reason for this is that, while 8 bits per component is common (hence hex codes) newer hardware supports 10 or 12 bits per component; and wider gamut colorspaces need more bits to avoid banding.

This bit-depth agnosticism is also why newer CSS color specifications use a 0 to 1 float range.

Having said which, the CSS Object Model still requires color values to be serialized at 8 bits per component. This is going to change, but the higher-precision replacement is still being discussed in the CSS working group. So for now, browsers don't let you get more than 8 bits per component of precision.

If you are converting a float or percentage form to hex (or to 0 - 255 integer) the correct method is rounding. Floor or ceiling will not spec the values evenly at the top or bottom of the range.